# PS command to pull logon Types assosciated with Specific event ID

Tags: windows, powershell

The follow code is the proposed solution to an online interactive lab.  This is the solution as provided by the lab creator. The intention is to use this to find a pass the hash login type (logon Type 9) tho in this example I am using type 3.

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName 'Security' -FilterXPath '*/*/EventID="4624" and */*/Data[@Name="LogonType"]="3"' -ComputerName <example dc> | Format-List | findstr /R \<Network.Account.Name\>
```

I would expect the list to be formatted list of users that had a 4624 event ID with a type 3 login.

But I get this..

```
            Network Account Name:   -
            Network Account Name:   -
            Network Account Name:   -
            Network Account Name:   -
            Network Account Name:   -
            Network Account Name:   -
            Network Account Name:   -
            Network Account Name:   -
            Network Account Name:   -
            Network Account Name:   -
            Network Account Name:   -
            Network Account Name:   -
            Network Account Name:   -
            Network Account Name:   -
            Network Account Name:   -
            Network Account Name:   -
            Network Account Name:   -
```

I'm not sure what the problem is but I am wondering if the Network.Account.Name is not the proper variable to use with this problem.

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.17763.1490
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.17763.1490
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

When removing the list formatting

```
 ProviderName: Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing

TimeCreated                     Id LevelDisplayName Message
-----------                     -- ---------------- -------
2/6/2021 8:06:28 PM           4624 Information      An account was successfully logged on....
2/6/2021 8:06:28 PM           4624 Information      An account was successfully logged on....
2/6/2021 8:06:27 PM           4624 Information      An account was successfully logged on....
2/6/2021 8:06:27 PM           4624 Information      An account was successfully logged on....
2/6/2021 8:06:27 PM           4624 Information      An account was successfully logged on....
2/6/2021 8:06:27 PM           4624 Information      An account was successfully logged on....
```

So it is finding the events...

Comment: How does the output look like when you remove `| findstr /R \<Network.Account.Name\>`?

Comment: Adding this to the origonal

Comment: I know this is already answered, but my 3 cents anyways.  Format-List and Format-Table return special format objects which in the most part are not useful for anything but viewing on the screen.  If used they typically always come at the end of the pipeline.  Additionally replace findstr with the Where-Object cmdlet for a more robust and powershell pipeline friendly solution, but place this before the Format-List cmdlet.

Answer (score 1):

You're using findstr to specifically look for the string <Network.Account.Name> and nothing else. That's why you're getting it. Also findstr has limited regex capabilities, so I would not use it for more complex requirements.

Try something like:

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName Security -FilterXPath '*/*/EventID="4624" and */*/Data[@Name="LogonType"]="3"' -ComputerName <example dc> | ? {$_.Message -match 'Network.Account.Name'} | select *
```

This will get your Security events, filter for text matching Network.Account.Name and expand it.

Comment: This returns an RPC error for me, that could be the lab environment tho.                        `Get-WinEvent : The RPC server is unavailable
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-WinEvent -LogName 'Security' -FilterXPath '*/*/EventID="4624" and ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-WinEvent], EventLogException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWinEventCommand`

Answer (score 0):

This should work in powershell 7, but I don't have that event type in my logs:

```
get-winevent @{logname='security'; id = 4624; logontype = 3}
```

Here's all the xml data in powershell 5 on a computer with matching logs.  "data = 3" is generic for any eventdata field that equals 3.  Actually, I don't see where "Network Account Name" comes from.  I would use this inside invoke-command for a remote computer.

```
get-winevent @{logname='security'; id = 4624; data = 3} -MaxEvents 1 | 
  % { ([xml]$_.toxml()).event.eventdata.data }

Name                      #text
----                      -----
SubjectUserSid            S-1-0-0
SubjectUserName           -
SubjectDomainName         -
SubjectLogonId            0x0
TargetUserSid             S-1-5-21-2423303272-2025932682-2187700762-274702
TargetUserName            js2010
TargetDomainName          stackoverflow.com
TargetLogonId             0x14529312
LogonType                 3
LogonProcessName          Kerberos
AuthenticationPackageName Kerberos
WorkstationName           -
LogonGuid                 {faa04afa-a7c8-23f4-b05c-aaff9e0ea54f}
TransmittedServices       -
LmPackageName             -
KeyLength                 0
ProcessId                 0x0
ProcessName               -
IpAddress                 -
IpPort                    -
ImpersonationLevel        %%1833
RestrictedAdminMode       -
TargetOutboundUserName    -
TargetOutboundDomainName  -
VirtualAccount            %%1843
TargetLinkedLogonId       0x0
ElevatedToken             %%1842
```